# Не выводится циклом данные из postgresDB в шаблон с помощью express

Tags: html, node.js, postgresql, express

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const pool = require('../database/pool');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
]
router.get('/pveLocations', async (req, res) => {
if (!req.session.userId) {
return res.redirect('/login');
}

try {
const result = await pool.query('SELECT "nameLocation", min_level FROM "pveLocations"');
res.render('pve', {
locations: result.rows
});
} catch (error) {
console.error(error);
res.status(500).send('Произошла ошибка сервера');
}
});

router.get('/pvelocations/:locationName', async (req, res) => {
const locationName = req.params.locationName;

try {
const result = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM "pveLocations" WHERE "location_slug" = $1', 
[locationName]);
if (result.rows.length > 0) {
res.render('localEternum', {
location: result.rows[0]
});
} else {
res.status(404).send('Локация не найдена');
}
} catch (error) {
console.error(error);
res.status(500).send('Произошла ошибка сервера');
}
});


module.exports = router;
```

Вот мой роут

В БД есть таблица pveLocations в ней колонка есть location_slug название ссылок на англ с нижним подчерквиванием пробелов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
вот мой

```
html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Адаптивная разметка</title>
<!-- Подключение Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="page-container">
<header class="header">



</header>

<main class="content">

<hr class="hr-dark-purple">
<div class="menu-container">
<!-- Список ссылок -->
```

-->

```
<% locations.forEach(function(location) { %>
<div class="location-item">
<a href="/pveLocations/" class="menu-link">
<%= location.nameLocation %>
<span class="location-level">(Требуется уровень: <%= location.min_level %>)</span>
</a>

</div>
<% }) %>
```

в который я пытаюсь циклом вывести все локации и это получается, но вот только при нажатии не происходит переход по ссылки и чтобы после перехода отоброжалась ссылка url localhost:3000/pveLocations/Forest_of_Eternum

Comment: Ты имеешь ввиду, чтобы вытягивать все без цикла?

Comment: в href атрибуте ссылки нехватает чего-то, что в роуте `/pvelocations/:locationName` станет locationName. `<a href="/pveLocations/<%= location.ВОТ_ТУТ_НУЖНО_ПОДСТАВИТЬ_ЧТО_ТО_ИДЕНТИФИЦИРУЮЩЕЕ_ЗАПИСЬ_НАПРИМЕР_ location_slug %>" class="menu-link">`